# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning: How does panda konw DataFrame was created as a slice from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How does python pandas know a DataFrame is a slice from another DataFrame? example 1 gives SettingWithCopyWarning:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([list(range(4)) for i in range(7)])
b=a[[1,2]]
b.loc[0,1]=7
```

:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy%60)

while example 2 does not:

```
b=a[[1,2]].copy()
b.loc[0,1]=7
```

Obviously pandas keeps track on DataFrame origins but how?

Pandas documentation suggests error is related to chained indexing not used in example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas keeps a reference to the original in the attribute whichever to assign a dataframe to a new variable without newly creating it or using `.copy()`. This is the default behaviour.

If it's a slice, this will give the reference to the original dataframe.

For your example "b"

```
b._is_copy
```

gives you something like

```
<weakref at 0x000001C14634F650; to 'DataFrame' at 0x000001C14F7EC3D0>
```

and

```
b._is_copy()
```

gives the content of the source dataframe.

If a dataframe is not a slice, but a real copy or an original, `.is_copy` is `None`.